# OAuth only working for some google accounts?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api

Oof. gotta love OAuth...

TLDR; the OAuth 2.0 code that I managed to cobble together from the only android calendar API sample project that I could find, only works on a few accounts.

Half my friends click the grey dialogue with their Gmail and select their account, the white+blue screen asking for consent appears, and boom! events are fetched from the google calendar.

the other half of my friends click the grey dialogue text with their Gmail, and no consent screen appears and it just flashes the grey dialogue with their Gmail prompting for them to select their account again.

Heres the cobbled-together code:

***My activity java:***
https://pastebin.com/mcxLfGZR

```
no code pasted because its very long
```

***Apisynctask.java to go with it:***
https://pastebin.com/p7Wx2Lm2

```
no code pasted once again
```

***My Activity.xml:***
https://pastebin.com/KELRqYHD
AND (goes with, because android studio templates...)
https://pastebin.com/Bbev37ye <--- the content for the above paste

```
no code pasted once again because long-ish
```

I believe this is either android version, google account, or device related, and cannot narrow it down at all.

Anyways, I would appreciate any help in getting this to work for everyone, instead of just a handful of people, like I said, it only works for me and half my friends. thanks!

Edit:
No error is thrown in logcat when the re-popup of it happens. the code jumps all the place, (I tried putting loge messages in each chunk of code to see where it was going, and where it was failing - to no end)

Answer (score 1):

You can set the [Authorization parameters](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#creatingclient) to create an authorization request.

> You can `prompt` the user to re-authorize your app by adding the
>   `prompt=consent` parameter to the authentication request. When
>   `prompt=consent` is included, the consent screen is displayed every time
>   the user logs into your app. For this reason, include `prompt=consent`
>   only when necessary.
>
> [**`prompt`**](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#authenticationuriparameters)
>
> **Optional**. A space-delimited, case-sensitive list of prompts to present the user. If you don't specify this parameter, the user will
>   be prompted only the first time your app requests access. Possible
>   values are:
>
> - `none` - The authorization server does not display any authentication or user consent screens; it will return an error if the user is not already authenticated and has not pre-configured consent for the requested scopes. You can use none to check for existing authentication and/or consent.
> - `consent` - The authorization server prompts the user for consent before returning information to the client.
> - `select_account` - The authorization server prompts the user to select a user account. This allows a user who has multiple accounts at the authorization server to select amongst the multiple accounts that they may have current sessions for.

**Note:** If no value is specified and the user has not previously authorized access, then the user is shown a consent screen.

Comment: I am still confused? this is for Android Java aswell?

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, this is for openID connect - allows clients of all types, including Web-based, mobile, and JavaScript clients, to request and receive information about authenticated sessions and end-users.